# Bitcoin Core Multi-wallet limit to 333 wallets

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, wallet.dat

Bitcoin Core 0.15.1 has [Multi wallets support](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.15.0#multi-wallet-support):

In the `bitcoin.conf` we can add multiple entries of:

```
wallet=wallet-1.dat
wallet=wallet-2.dat
wallet=wallet-3.dat
wallet=wallet-4.dat
...
wallet=wallet-350.dat
```

When Bitcoin Core starts, if the wallet file does not exists it will create it. which is great for our needs.

However, it **always** crashes on the 333 wallet. with `db.log` error:

```
Lock table is out of available locker entries
```

And `debug.log`:

```
2018-02-13 14:47:05 init message: Loading wallet...
2018-02-13 14:47:05 nFileVersion = 160000
2018-02-13 14:47:05 Keys: 21 plaintext, 0 encrypted, 21 w/ metadata, 21 total
2018-02-13 14:47:05  wallet                   36ms
2018-02-13 14:47:05 setKeyPool.size() = 20
2018-02-13 14:47:05 mapWallet.size() = 0
2018-02-13 14:47:05 mapAddressBook.size() = 0
2018-02-13 14:47:05 init message: Loading wallet...
2018-02-13 14:47:05 

************************
EXCEPTION: St13runtime_error       
CDB: Error 12, can't open database wallet-333.dat       
D:\BitcoinCore\bitcoin-0.16.0\bin\bitcoin-qt.exe in Runaway exception
```

I also tried to minimize the `-keypool=20` so that the wallets size will be much smaller in size, and the process of loading them is much faster.

I was suggested that this error is because each wallet.dat file is opened in the same BDB environment. The entire environment has a limited number of database locks, and it seems like 333 wallets hits that number of database locks.

The solution (which did not work) is to create a file named `DB_CONFIG` in the data dir, and put the following lines in that file:

```
set_lk_max_locks 400000
set_lk_max_objects 400000
```

By default it is 40000 and now 400000 (ten times more locks available)

But this gave the same results.

I tried also:

```
set_lg_dir database
```

With no luck.

I verified this on two different Windows 10 machines with 0.15.1 and 0.16.0. Same result. It always crashes when loading the 333 wallet.

Anyone have a solution to this?

I have put the list of wallets if anyone care to reproduce: https://pastebin.com/8wHD1tL3

Comment: For starters, you should file a bug report.  Even if there is a limit, the client should fail gracefully when the limit is reached, instead of crashing.  https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. Adding

```
set_lk_max_lockers 400000
```

Did the trick.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/api_reference/C/set_lk_max_lockers_parameter.html

I tested and was able to auto-create and load 932 wallets, until I hit an out of memory error:

```
Logging region out of memory; you may need to increase its size
DB_TXN->abort: log undo failed for LSN: 227 171878: Not enough space
PANIC: Not enough space
PANIC: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
```

Setting:

```
set_lg_regionmax 1048576
```

Resolves the above `Logging region out of memory; you may need to increase its size` issue.

Comment: can you please tell me where you kept this `set_lk_max_lockers 400000` ?? in db.cpp ? https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/wallet/db.cpp#L166

Comment: I've created DB_CONFIG file in data directory of core daemon and given two values as mentioned but still its i am getting same issue daemon crashed after 250+ wallets can you please guide me or share how to use above things?

Comment: Yes DB_CONFIG  is in the datadir as far as I can recall. I think  I also minimized the `-keypool=20` (or 10). In any case  I dumped this idea and I don't recommend going that path.

Comment: So is there any otherway..?

Comment: I mean if found anything ...please suggest .. thanks..

Comment: The other way is to manually manage the private keys/wallets. It's much harder but you are not limited in any way.